# file viewController.swift is part of module "coreData" ignoring import

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I tried to import CoreData and it came up with a warning "file viewController.swift is part of module "coreData" ignoring import"
[A Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJcV2.png)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: is your project name is something related to "Coredata". ?

Comment: This issue comes when your CoreData's database name same as your project name.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Is your project name "CoreData" ? You can't call your project with the name of a module. Try creating another project with another name

Comment: Is there a way to fix this without renaming the project/target?

Comment: better to rename your project... as apple not going to rename framework :)

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks